# to Type running off page with Lattice & ggplot2 graphics using knitr, pandoc, Rmd, to PDF

Tags: r, knitr, lattice, r-markdown

I am really digging into R-Markdown as a method of performing reproducible research. I have been successful in processing my Rmd files to both HTML and MS Word using knitr and pandoc (including passing both text and images through pander for fancifying). HTML is pretty straight forward, Word did a reasonable enough job (I had to do some additional formatting before submitting that manuscript).

Now, I'm trying to convert to PDF. I have customized the yaml header to look like this:

```
bibliography: citations.bib
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_crop: no
    fig_height: 3
    fig_width: 4.5
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
  word_document:
    fig_caption: yes
documentclass: article
csl: vancouver.csl
```

I am having one hell of a time with a very strange effect. Tables are set properly in the text, no problem. However, graphs (does not matter if it is ggplot2 or lattice) are hosing the typesetting up pretty badly. I've included a screencap to show you what is happening with the text. The image is up at the top of that page, and it's like the conversion to PDF considers the image as a line or two of text and does not account for the actual vertical space it is taking up. The page number is placed properly on the page as you will see, but text just keeps running all the way off and disappears into nothing. It's not on the next page, it's just gone.

Anyone seen something like this before? Is there something dumb I am doing?

Here's an example of a code block that creates an image with this phenomenon.

````
```{r echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This graph is going to be AWESOME."}
xyplot(x ~ y | z, myData, pch=19, type = c('p', 'r'), xlab="x-vals", ylab="y-vals", as.table=TRUE)
```
````

[image: Screencap showing the problem]

The above screencap that shows the problem. The line in the middle is the page divider in the R PDF viewer.

Comment: As a follow-up, we are also working this issue on the [pandoc-discuss Google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/pandoc-discuss/20150211192502.GA11303%40protagoras.berkeley.edu). As it turns out, there is an issue with LaTeX and \longtable with pandoc. Will post solutions at some point.